# What is the status of the nation of Chondath in the Forgotten Realms of 5th Edition D&D?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms

The 4th Edition *Forgotten Realms Campaign Guide* indicates that Chondath was among the lands "most changed by the Spellplague" (p. 50), inasmuch as the entire nation was "obliterated" (p. 100) in the violent merging of Abeir with Toril. "[T]he strip of land formerly called Chondath" was either subsumed into the Abeiran realm of Akanûl (p. 86) -- now littered with "[t]he shattered ruins of Chondathan cities" (p. 90) -- or else became part of a frontier called the Vilhon Wilds (p. 193).

All of that [happened in the late 14th century DR](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Spellplague), with 4th Edition officially starting in 1479 DR (see *FRCG* p. 40).

Starting in the 1480s, the Second Sundering separated Abeir and Toril once more, and [5th Edition is set circa 1489 DR](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/82732/when-in-universe-does-5e-dd-take-place/).

Popular opinion seems to hold (not without [evidence](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/108252/why-did-ed-greenwood-and-r-a-salvatore-dislike-the-spellplague-arc), granted) that 5E was intended to roll back some of 4E's more drastic lore changes, leaving the state of the world roughly compatible with pre-4E lore. However, even with Akanûl returned to Abeir, the ten-year stretch between 1479 and 1489 seems awfully short for Chondath to have been rebuilt from blasted ruins into the functioning nation it was before 4E.

Mysteriously, the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* mentions various other nations around the Sea of Fallen Stars, such as Aglarond, Chessenta, Impiltur, and Thesk (see p. 11-13), yet there is no mention of Chondath.

**Is there *any* available information on the state of Chondath as of 1489?**

Answer (score 2):

I have found absolutely no mention in the SCAG about Chondath.

The Forgotten Realms Wiki article on [Chondath](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Chondath) says (emphasis mine):

> **Chondath** was a country located in the Vilhon Reach. It had a long history.

It also says:

> In 1386 DR, as part of the Spellplague, most of Chondath was exchanged with parts of the Abeiran land of Shyr. What remained of Chondath on Toril was utterly destroyed by the subsequent catastrophes of the Wailing Years.

That leads us to believe there is no more Chondath. I am not sure of the reliability of Forgotten Realms Wiki, but that is all I found.

Comment: "The mentions of "had" and "was" lead us to believe that it is gone." - Not quite. [FR wiki has a past-tense policy](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Forgotten_Realms_Wiki:Past-tense_policy) in order to stay edition-neutral and avoid specifying a "present day" in-universe: "The use of past tense neatly avoids all these issues, by setting events in stone as soon as they occur. Therefore, to maintain a consistent writing style, to eliminate chronology errors, and be equally accepting of all editions and appealing to all fans, the Forgotten Realms Wiki adopted this past-tense policy."

Comment: "[...] It does not mean everything is dead and gone, that dwarves and gold dragons are extinct, that Eshpurta is destroyed, or Drizzt Do'Urden is deceased. Instead, this use of past tense is a form of narrative tense used for storytelling purposes, as used in most novels and every Forgotten Realms novel."

Comment: Okay, thanks for the notification. But the part saying "was utterly destroyed" will lead us to the belief that it was destroyed.

Comment: That's fair, I just wanted to point out that the use of past tense on FR wiki is for a different reason than you thought. You may want to edit the answer to remove that claim and focus just on the mention of Chondath being "utterly destroyed". ...Also, the quoted claim about it being destroyed does have 2 citations, so rather than saying "I'm not sure of the reliability of Forgotten Realms Wiki", you could improve the answer by directly stating what sources the article cites for the quoted claim (and verifying that they support that claim, if you are able to verify that yourself). :)

Comment: Ok , I appreciate the notification, I am new to the fandom sites. I will edit that now